# Sum function of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-series

Does anyone know what is the sum function $f(x)$ of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$? I have no idea how to find a sum function... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Another method:

Define $$f:(0,2\pi)\to \mathbb{R},\ f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}$$Then it easily follows that  $$\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}=-\sum_{n\ge 1}\cos nx=\frac{1}{2}\implies f(x)=x^2/4+Bx+C$$ Note that the equalities are in $L^2$ sense. Then $f(0)=C\implies C=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $f(2\pi)=\pi^2+C+2\pi B=\pi^2/6\implies B=-\pi/2\implies f(x)=x^2/4-\pi x/2+\pi^2/6 $. Then by periodicity we can extend the domain of $f$ to the whole real line.

Comment: Periodically extended, of course. It's funny how it's completely unapparent how this continuous procedure should produce a nonanalytic periodic function with sharp corners. Of course, the catch is in the $\sum \cos n x$ which isn't $\frac12$ when $\cos nx=1$ (there's a delta function contribution there).

Comment: Yes, @orion, that's true. Should I define the function $f$ on $(0,2\pi)$ initially to avoid confusion and then say that it is periodically extended to other intervals?

Comment: Yes, as this is a Fourier series with obvious periodicity, it's perfectly reasonable to state at the beginning $f: (0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks @orion, I will make that edit in my answer.

Comment: That proof seems very incorrect. The sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geqslant 1} \cos nx$ doesn't even converge anywhere.

Comment: @Adayah well most Fourier series don't converge in the cleanest sense. But I guess it would be more sensible to just look up $\sum_{n>0} \cos n x$ as the dirac comb transform without the zeroth term.

Comment: Then I think it should be emphasized if the notation is used in a sense different than commonly understood, even if that sense is common among Fourier series specialists, because the question is a bit simpler than that.

Comment: @Adayah, I guess I should specify that the equalities are in $L^2$ sense.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Fourier series.  The derivative is a "sawtooth" function.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not sure what a sum function would mean. Can you please give a suggestion? How is the derivative helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Fourier series expasion of a function $g(x)$:

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ i n x} c_n$$

where

$$ c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx} g(x) dx.$$

Calculate the coefficients of the functions: $x^2,x,c$. $f$ will be a linear combination of these.

$$ f(x) = \alpha x^2 +\beta x +\gamma$$

thus $c_n(f) = \alpha c_n(x^2) +\beta c_n(x) +\gamma \overset{!}{=} \frac{1}{n^2}$. Solve for the coefficients $\alpha,\ \beta,\ \gamma$.

Comment: Do you mean the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$, or some others? If I've already found $a_n$ and $b_n$, how do I use them? Or is it $x^n$ for every $n$? I'm confused, sorry.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin(nx) f(x)dx$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(nx) f(x)dx$. Well it should be clear the all the $a_n$ should add to zero, then the $b_n$ must add to $1/n^2$

Comment: But then it seems like we will have infinitely many solutions for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: The equation must hold for all $n$. You compare coefficients, so on the right side there is just $1/n^2$, then on the left side the terms with $1/n$ and the constant terms must add to zero. There should be just one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n^2}$$

so that $\Re g(x) = f(x)$. Now,

$$g'(x)= i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n} = -i\log(1-e^{ix})$$

which converges, since we know $\sum x^n/n$ converges when $|x|\le 1$. Taking the real part of $g'$:

$$\Re \left(-i\log(1-e^{ix})\right) = \arg (1-e^{ix}) = -\arctan\left(\cot\left(\frac x2\right)\right)$$

which is just a periodic set of lines in the form $y=(x-\pi)/2$ with a period of $w\pi$. Integrating this, we get

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}x+C$$

since $f(0) = \pi^2/6$, we finally get

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}x+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

for $x\in[0, 2\pi]$. The rest of the function is defined by $2\pi$-periodicity.

Comment: "converges when $|x|≤1$" except for $x=1$, see harmonic series.